# why does my graphql return an empty array?

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo-client, strapi, graphql-js

I am newbie with graphql. I have a front-end project (nextjs) and  back-end(strapi).

This is my code

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from '@apollo/client'

export default function Blog({ posts }) {
  console.log('posts', posts)
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(post => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{posts.heading}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql/',
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        posts {
          data {
            attributes {
              heading
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  })

  return {
    props: {
      posts: data.posts,
    },
  }
}
```

alongside this, I also get this message "cannot destructure property of intermediate value". Does anybody know why, i'm sure the code is correct.

Comment: `const response = await client.query ... ` log response, destructure later ... query tested using postman/playground?

Comment: Can you show me a working example please.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i recommend creating a folder in root and put all graphql codes and you have also a syntax error:
let me give you an example:
/index.js

```js
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: API,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  defaultOptions: {
    query: {
      fetchPolicy: "network-only",
    },
  },
});

//get category ids
const getCatIds = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await client.query({
      query: gql`
        query categoriesId {
          categories(sort: "id:ASC") {
            id
            name
          }
        }
      `,
    });
    return data.categories;
  } catch {
    console.log("error appolo");
  }
};
export {getCatIds}
```